# Get range of ordered array from unsorted array

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I have an unsorted array and I am looking for an algorithm to extract a part / slice of that array when it would be sorted.

Example:

```
unsorted array
2 | 3 | 1 | 9 | 5 | 4 | 7 | 3 | 3

sorted:
1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 9

result for slice Index 5 - 7: 
4 | 5 | 7
```

Is there a better algorithm than sorting the whole array and then extracting the required range?

I know it is possible to get the final position of an element in O(n). That is more or less how quick sort works. I would need the final element for a given position.

I am using C# for the implementation.

Comment: `Is there a better algorithm than sorting the whole array and then extracting the required range?` How fast is it? Is it fast enough?

Comment: Finding the final position is O(n) for a *single* element. But you'll have to do it for *all* elements, so this would be O(n^2) for a naive implementation. And no, the lower bound for sorting is not O(n) but O(n * log(n))

Comment: If the slice indexes actually cover the entire array, it means you can't go faster than O(NlogN), since that's the bound for sorting algorithms

Comment: There are specialized algorithms for finding the k-largest (smallest) element but for your case you would need to apply them multiple times (ie find the 5th, 6th, and 7th element), so the gain might be marginally (if even existing).

Comment: So if this is a theoretical question, you might find better answers on https://cs.stackexchange.com. If this is a question for practical use, you first should evaluate, if just sorting the array might be fast enough anyways ...

Comment: @derpirscher there is no need to apply l-largest a lot of times - only two calls to separate larger and smaller parts.

Comment: @MBo how will separating by the 5th largest element give any clues about the 7th largest element (assuming the separation algorithms doesn't sort the partitions)

Comment: @derpirscher Of course, one have to sort middle part after partitions, if sorted result is needed (assuming that slice size is small relative to the whole array)

Comment: @derpirscher Perhaps I understood your question wrong. The second call works with smaller array: `ksmallest(A, 0, size(A), k_upper); ksmallest(A, 0, k_upper, k_lower); treat slice k_lower..k_upper`

Comment: Here's a variation on MBo's approach. Partition the array, and there are two cases. 1) All of the elements of the slice are in one of the partitions. In this case, you now have a smaller array to work with. 2) Elements of the slice are in both partitions (i.e. the pivot used to partition is a member of the slice). In this case, find the k1-largest of the left partition, and the k2-smallest of the right partition (where `sum(k1, k2) == length(slice)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) would give you an average of O(N), but worst case of O(N^2).
A better algorithm is [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect) which has the same average but worst case is O(N lg N).
Both has the problem of a bad or malicious pivot would cause worst case behavior, to remedy this you would have to us a [median of median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) pivot selector.

Once you have made this you can get your range in O(N)

Pseudo code ahead.

```
low = nth_element(v, start, end, lowpos);
high = nth_element(v, low, end, highpos); // off by one?
range = sort(v, low, high); // M = high-low, O(M lg M)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. We still ended up sorting the whole array though, because in the benchmarks this was still faster for many of our use cases.